# Need to show negitive results from search (Wordpress Plugin)

Tags: php, wordpress

I've been working on showing a list of posts that users have NOT favoured using this wordpress plugin: https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/favorites/

I've re-created a search that I can make into a custom shortcode, but I can't work out how to reverse it to show UNfavorited lists.

Also, I would like to show the title and have the title link to the page - can anyone help? This is what I have:

```
$favorites = get_user_favorites();

    if ( $favorites ) :

    $favorites_query = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post__in' => $favorites
    ));

    if ( $favorites_query->have_posts() ) :

        while ( $favorites_query->have_posts() ) : $favorites_query->the_post();

            echo '<p>' . get_the_title( $favorite ) . '</p>';

        endwhile;

    endif;

    wp_reset_postdata();

endif;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder if you mean:

```
 $favorites_query = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post__not_in' => $favorites
    ));
```

where we use `post__not_in`  instead of `post__in` ?

From the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters):

> `post__not_in` (array) - use post ids. Specify post NOT to retrieve. If
>   this is used in the same query as `post__in`, it will be ignored.

But note that the amount of returned posts could be large with `posts_per_page` as -1.

Comment: Thank you so much, I've spent 9 hours trying to work that out.

Comment: You're welcome, glad to hear it's what you were looking for. @JoeMarshall